# select() wont timeout after send()

Tags: c++, sockets, select, timeout, udp

I started to lock into socket programming an got into a little trouble:
I created the small program below which sends a  message via udp an receives one if possible in a loop. I want to try that with multiple sockets later on, so I use `select()`.

When I use my `127.0.0.1`, `select()` gives a timeout in the first loop (after `send()`) but after that it always returns `1` indicating that the socket is readable without receiving a message:

```
//C++
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKADDR_IN RemoteAddr;
SOCKADDR_IN OwnAddr;
SOCKET UDP_Socket1;
fd_set m_Fds;
struct timeval m_Timeout;
int iRemoteAddrLenght = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);
int i = 0;

//--Init
WSAStartup (MAKEWORD (2,2), &wsa);
UDP_Socket1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
m_Timeout.tv_sec = 2;
m_Timeout.tv_usec = 0;

RemoteAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
RemoteAddr.sin_port = htons (2002);
RemoteAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");   

OwnAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
OwnAddr.sin_port = htons (2003);
OwnAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

bind(UDP_Socket1, (SOCKADDR*) &OwnAddr, sizeof(OwnAddr));

for(;;)
{
    //..//
    //--send
    sendto(UDP_Socket1, sSend.c_str(), strlen(sSend.c_str()), 0 ,  (SOCKADDR*)&RemoteAddr, sizeof(RemoteAddr));

    //--select & recv
    FD_ZERO(&m_Fds);
    FD_SET(UDP_Socket1,&m_Fds);
    i = select(sizeof(m_Fds)*8, &m_Fds, NULL, NULL, &m_Timeout);
    if(i > 0)
    {
        recvfrom(UDP_Socket1, m_szBuff, 256, 0, (SOCKADDR*) &RemoteAddr, &m_iRemoteAddrLenght);
    } //if
    else if(i < 1)        // "0" in 1st loop, then "1" =(
    {
        cout << "Udp Timeout" << endl;    
    } //else if
} //for
```

`send` returns `56` (bytes send)
with `WSAGetLastError: 0`

`recvfrom` returns `-1`
with `WSAGetLastError: 10054`

I'd appreciate your help about why `select()` returns `1` when it should timeout

Comment: Where you create the socket, you must tell it that you want a UDP one: the third parameter must be IPPROTO_UDP

Comment: `UDP_Socket1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);` is still the same

Comment: if `recvfrom` returns -1 and `WSAGetLastError` return 10054 (`WSAECONNRESET`), according to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120.aspx) it means that the send actually failed (ICMP Port Unreachable). Try to check for errors in the select by passing another fd_set as fourth parameter.

Comment: ´i = select(sizeof(m_Fds)*8, NULL, NULL, &m_Fds, &m_Timeout);´ returns "0"; when I add a second fd_set with my socket and pass it to select like this: ´int i = select(1,&m_Fds, NULL, &m_Fds2, &m_Timeout);´ it still returns "1"                  and would you be so kind and explain why recvfrom() cares about sendto()?  I thought Udp is all about just firing a message and not caring about it later on...? thanks in advance

Comment: sry, took too long to edit: `i = select(sizeof(m_Fds)*8, NULL, NULL, &m_Fds, &m_Timeout);` returns "0"; when I add a second fd_set with my socket and pass it to select like this: `int i = select(1,&m_Fds, NULL, &m_Fds2, &m_Timeout);` it still returns "1". ...                  and would you be so kind and explain why recvfrom() cares about sendto()?  I thought Udp is all about just firing a message and not caring about it later on...? thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I mean something like: `select(0, &m_Fds, NULL, &m_Err, &m_Timeout)` then you can check if the socket is ready for receive or in error. Also, are you sure that you want to send the packet to localhost?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why recvfrom returns error if sendto failed, I've simply read it on the documentation. Here you can find something related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372371/error-receiving-in-udp-connection-refused

Comment: `select(0, &m_Fds, NULL, &m_Err, &m_Timeout)` returns the "1"/0 with `FD_ZERO(&m_Err);` executed first (with a "beep" over my speakers..?) and without that: "-1" / 10055. (m_Error only declared, not filled with the socket, I hope that's what you meant)    By using localhost I could try my programs and send and recv without using another machine (which I dont have =)

Comment: you should fill m_Error too. However, do you have something listening on port 2002 on your machine?

Comment: I treated my `&m_Fds2`exactly like `&m_Fds` so I guess that's covered. And I changed the part about the ports and enter various port no whenever I compile the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore these kinds of errors for UDP. Some operating systems report them, some don't. They're basically meaningless.